# Classic Asp - Get html content after generated page/page load

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, pdf-generation

I´m using AspPDF together with Classic ASP to create PDF files and I have a page that is build dinamically based on POST requests.

After that, I need to get this HTML that has been dinamically created and insert all of it inside a variable, so then I can send it to AspPDF method at the end of the page.
(I know AspPDF has a method that converts page based on URL, it does not work for me in my specific case)

Because I have several if statements and loops, I have no idea how to store all current HTML generated in a variable.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i am not familiar with AspPDF, but my question is:
can you store everything in some variable and once html completly generated then send content by using

```
Response.Write VarHTML
```

> Because I have several if statements and loops, I have no idea how to store all current HTML generated in a variable.

like this:

```
VarHTML = VarHTML & "your html code"
```

VarHTML -- just variable you create

Comment: I can´t just 'varhtml = varhtml & "my code" because the structure of the page, it has several nested loops and if statements that doing like this would make a huge spaghetti code.
But the concept is pretty much like that, I just need the whole dinamically generated code inside a variable. After that I could just send it to AspPDF.

Comment: From what i know -- no other way to do this. You could keep everything in "buffer", but you cannot read "buffer". 

Response.Buffer = True

Comment: What if after the pages been generated, I save all html in a text/tmp file (on server, not client´s computer) then I read it back and insert its contents inside a variable?
Is there a way to do this in ASP?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know such way.

Comment: @Art You could probably do that with a FileSystemObject. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_filesystem.asp .   Bear in mind though that if you're converting HTML to a pdf then you're probably going to need to render it in a browser to turn it into something readable.  This is why components like AspPDF and AbcPDF use the server's instance of Internet Explorer